# Euribor rates in XML

Tags: xml, rss, rates

I need Euribor rates to calculate mortgage rates on a website. 
Does anybody know if there is any service that provides this data, maybe in XML format? 
A RSS feed would be ok, free or paid.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comercial provider of such service:

http://www.xignite.com/xInterbanks.asmx?op=GetEURIBOR

Comment: thanks! that solved it! (I meanwhile found some free providers, but I don't trust them... they might be down one day or another)

Answer (score 2):

I found an active link which provide an open csv file, the data source can be trusted I think. It's provided by the french bank. If it can help.

[Here - http://www.banque-france.fr/economie-et-statistiques/changes-et-taux/les-taux-interbancaires.html](http://www.banque-france.fr/economie-et-statistiques/changes-et-taux/les-taux-interbancaires.html)

Answer (score 2):

I like Quandl, i is a real playground for various data series.

First 3-Month Euribor hits I got:

- http://www.quandl.com/BOF/QS_M_IEUTIO3M-EURIBOR-3-Months-Monthly
- http://www.quandl.com/BOE/IUQAERB3-Euribor-3-Month