# How to get interest rates and interbank rates in C#?

Tags: c#, csv, yahoo, finance, rates

There is a nice [Yahoo-Managed](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/) open source project that allows to get stock prices, exchange rates, technical charts etc from Yahoo.

Unfortunately, Yahoo doesn't provide interest rates and interbank rates such as EURIBOR.

I found a link that allows to get [EURIBOR](http://www.banque-france.fr/en/economics-statistics/rates/main-euro-area-interbank-market-rates.html) as .csv (French Bank). On the Federal Reserve [website](http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Choose.aspx?rel=h15), there is a way to get their interest rates.

The question is: is there any API that allows to get interest rates from one place (or project that wraps the process of getting the rates from different sources)?

**EDIT:**
After googling on the matter, i found at least 4 data sources that more or less meet the requirements. I hope this would be helpful for someone else.

1. [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/) - Federal Reserve Economic Data. Provides a comprehensive
   list of data series with financial data. Accumulates data from
   different sources (Eurostat, IMF, etc). They also have an [API](http://api.stlouisfed.org/docs/fred/?utm_source=research&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=data-tools)
   which works quite well.
2. [Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/eurostat/home) - Provides health, education, financial and other
   statistics. They have no API, however there is a [bulk download
   concept](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/statistics/bulk_download) giving you the ability to get the data programmatically.
   At the top of this scheme is the [table of contents](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/NavTree_prod/everybody/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&file=table_of_contents.xml) that
   encloses all available data tables with references to the real data.
3. [ECB](http://www.ecb.int/stats/services/sdw/html/index.en.html) - One more data source where you find interesting financial
   statistics. They provide SDMX-based services to obtain the data
   programmatically. There is a nice [guide](http://stats.ecb.int/stats/sdw/docu/sdw_webservices_publicversion.pdf) that discovers these
   services.
4. [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/) - Provides health, environment, financial and other
   statistics. The have an [API](http://data.worldbank.org/developers) to get these data.

Using these data sources I was abble to create a generalized interface to get the data.

Comment: Isnt't this question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408702/euribor-rates-in-xml

Comment: yes, it is. But I'm looking for the API / Project for getting interest rates and interbank rates, but not only the EURIBOR

Answer (score 1):

The [Tradelink](http://tradelink.org) project has hooks to various data sources.

For historical data you can try [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/).